# how to change active class in php code

Tags: php, wordpress

index.php

```
<?php
     $cur_page = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1; //get curent page
     $offers_per_page = couponxl_get_option( 'offers_per_page' );

     $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'offer',
        'posts_per_page'=> $offers_per_page,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'meta_key'      => 'offer_expire',
        'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
        'page'         => $cur_page,
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
            'key' => 'offer_store',
            'value' => get_the_ID(),
            'compare' => '='
         ),
         array(
            'key' => 'offer_start',
            'value' => current_time( 'timestamp' ),
            'compare' => '<='
         ),
         array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                     'key' => 'offer_expire',
                     'value' => current_time( 'timestamp' ),
                     'compare' => '>='
                ),
                array(
                     'key' => 'offer_expire',
                     'value' => '-1',
                     'compare' => '='
                )
          ),
          array(
              'relation' => 'OR',
              array(
                  'key' => 'deal_status',
                  'value' => 'sold_out',
                  'compare' => '!='
              ),
              array(
                 'key' => 'deal_status',
                 'value' => 'sold_out',
                 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
              ),
           ),
        )
       );


       if( !empty( $offer_type ) ){
           $args['meta_query'][] = array(
           'key' => 'offer_type',
           'value' => $offer_type,
           'compare' => '='
       );
       }

       $offers = new WP_Query( $args );
       $page_links_total =  $offers->max_num_pages;
       $pagination_args = array(
       'end_size' => 2,
       'mid_size' => 2,
       'total' => $page_links_total,
       'current' => $cur_page, 
       'prev_next' => false,
       'type' => 'array'
       );
       if( isset( $offer_type ) ){
           $pagination_args['format'] = !get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ? '?page=%#%' : 'page/%#%';
       }
       $page_links = paginate_links( $pagination_args );
           $pagination = couponxl_format_pagination( $page_links );
           if( $offers->have_posts() ){                    
                $col = 6;
                if( $offer_view == 'list' ){
                    $col = 12;
                }
           ?>
<?php if( !empty( $pagination ) ): ?>
    <div class="col-sm-<?php echo esc_attr( $col ) ?> masonry-item">
        <ul class="pagination">
             <?php echo $pagination; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

function.php

```
function couponxl_format_pagination( $page_links ){    
    global $couponxl_slugs;
    $list = '';
    if (!empty($page_links)) {
        foreach ($page_links as $page_link) {
            if (strpos($page_link, 'page-numbers current') !== false) {
                $page_link = str_replace("<span class='page-numbers current'>", '<a href="javascript:;">', $page_link);
                $page_link = str_replace('</span>', '</a>', $page_link);
                $list .= '<li class="active">'.$page_link.'</li>';
            } else {
                if (get_query_var($couponxl_slugs['coupon']) && get_option('permalink_structure')) {
                    $page_link = preg_replace('#coupon\\/(.*?)/#i', '', $page_link, -1);
                } else {
                    $page_link = preg_replace('#(&\\#038\\;' . $couponxl_slugs['coupon'] . '|&' . $couponxl_slugs['coupon'] . ')=(.*?)&#i', '&', $page_link);
                    $page_link = preg_replace('#(&\\#038\\;' . $couponxl_slugs['coupon'] . '|&' . $couponxl_slugs['coupon'] . ')=(.*?)\'#i', '\'', $page_link );
                }               
                $list .= '<li>' . $page_link . '</li>';
            }
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
```

When I change page number so page changed but page active class not change is always active page number 1 and when I click again page number 1 is not working is activate and not change in deactivate. Please tell me what I do pagination not working properly and active code not working properly.

follow this link:- http://www.cuponswall.in/store/flipkart-coupons-offers

pagination not working on this page

Comment: I have a problem on my site when I upload selected coupon on my home page but coupons show randomly not selected when I refresh page again change coupon and I also face this problem my other inner pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be changed like blow:

(file: function.php)

```
function couponxl_format_pagination( $page_links, $cur_page ){    
    global $couponxl_slugs;
    $list = '';
    if (!empty($page_links)) {
        foreach ($page_links as $page_link) {
            if (strpos($page_link, 'page-numbers current') !== false) {
                $page_link = str_replace("<span class='page-numbers current'>", '<a href="javascript:;">', $page_link);
                $page_link = str_replace('</span>', '</a>', $page_link);
                $act_class = $page_link_n = '';  
                $page_link_n = strip_tags($page_link);                
                if($cur_page == $page_link_n) $act_class=' class="active"';
                $list .= '<li'.$act_class.'>'.$page_link.'</li>';
            } else {
                if (get_query_var($couponxl_slugs['coupon']) && get_option('permalink_structure')) {
                    $page_link = preg_replace('#coupon\\/(.*?)/#i', '', $page_link, -1);
                } else {
                    $page_link = preg_replace('#(&\\#038\\;' . $couponxl_slugs['coupon'] . '|&' . $couponxl_slugs['coupon'] . ')=(.*?)&#i', '&', $page_link);
                    $page_link = preg_replace('#(&\\#038\\;' . $couponxl_slugs['coupon'] . '|&' . $couponxl_slugs['coupon'] . ')=(.*?)\'#i', '\'', $page_link );
                }               
                $list .= '<li>' . $page_link . '</li>';
            }
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
```

update:
    use the function `strip_tags()` can get the page number of `$page_link`,so make the judge work.

Comment: not working all button are deactivate and button number 1 not working

Comment: Can you print_r($page_links), so we can get more information.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) when i print $page_link

Comment: I had modify the answer, so you can try again.

Comment: I have a problem on my site when I upload selected coupon on my home page but coupons show randomly not selected when I refresh page again change coupon and I also face this problem my other inner pages.